# How to show Joomla 3.4.8 banners as a slide

Tags: joomla-3.x

How do I show Joomla 3.4.8 banners as a slide, by taking into consideration the categories of the banners?

Comment: If you want a slide, you'll need to look for an extension on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/)

Comment: what extension do you recommand?

Comment: Funnily enough, I've never used the standard Joomla banners, but there are loads of sliders/carousels to choose from the Banner Management category: http://extensions.joomla.org/category/ads-a-affiliates/banner-management

Comment: Thank you, i have found in the category you sent me this extention "CAROUSEL BANNER" and it was exactly what i was looking for, thank you.

Comment: No worries. Please add your answer with the extension you chose and mark is as accepted.

Comment: i can't accept my own question until 2 days later, please answer, and i'll mark it as accepted, im new to this so ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to the comments, the OP has solved the issue by choosing the following extensions:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/ads-a-affiliates/banner-management/carousel-banner

to cater for their needs.